# Write BLE Characteristic in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can read the Characteristic but I couldn't write

I'm using the GattCallback function and I defined and declare all need properties inside of this function but somehow write function does not start

Here is my Gattcallback function

```
private BluetoothGattCallback bleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

        gatt.discoverServices();
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID_Service);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic charc= service.getCharacteristic(UUID_characteristic);
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(charc);
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {


        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID_Service);


        int data1 = 02;
        int data2 = 40;
        int data3 = 0;

         data1 = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
         data2 = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
         data3 = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;

        byte[] value = new byte[]{(byte)data1 , (byte)data2 ,(byte)data3};

        characteristic.setValue(value);
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

    }
};
```

I expected run write function but I can only connect the device
How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you want to write, or are you writting and expecting onCharacteristicWrite() to be called?

Comment: I want to write. anyway I create service in my costum function and it worked. Thanks